# Javascript, Change google map marker color

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

May I know a way to change the Google Map marker color via Javascript.. I am new at this and any help would be much appreciated, Thank you.

I used the following code to create a marker

```
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], 
     locations[i][2]),
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     map: map
 });
```

Answer (score 179, accepted):

In Google Maps API v3 you can try changing marker icon. For example for green icon use:

```
marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')
```

Or as part of marker init:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: 'http://...'
});
```

Other colors:

- http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png
- http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png

Etc.

Comment: Thank you very much :) this is what i was looking for :) may i know, do i apply this inside the place where i instantiate the marker as i ve show or is it defined outside seperately?  :)

Comment: Both work. Either you can add `icon` attribute and set it, or use `setIcon`. I'll add note about this.

Comment: Best answer in all stackoverflow so far!

Comment: These icons don't come with letters, it seems. Find these at  https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_greenA.png.

Comment: Is there a way to see all the icons?  I tried taking off the `blue-dot` and got a 404

Answer (score 41):

You can use the `strokeColor` property:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    id: "some-id",
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        strokeColor: "red",
        scale: 3
    },
    map: map,
    title: "some-title",
    position: myLatlng
});
```

See [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Symbols) for other possibilities.

Answer (score 16):

You can use this code it works fine.

```
 var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/009900/");

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: yourlatlong,
            icon: pinImage,
            map: map
        });
```

[see Example here](http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/)

Answer (score 15):

you can use the google chart api and generate any color with rgb code on the fly:

example: marker with #ddd color:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|ddd
```

include as stated above with

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: marker,
    title: 'Hello World',
    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|ddd'
});
```

Comment: true it can, **generate any color with rgb code on the fly**

Comment: I am using this very nice icon library for markers 
http://www.iconarchive.com/

It has some predefined sizes which is very useful for quick design.

Comment: looks really powerful and flexible but unfortunately this API was turned off in March 2019 https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons

Answer (score 9):

I really liked the answer given by Bahadır Yağan except I didn't like depending on a limited set of icons given by Google or an external API to generate my marker icons. Here is the initial solution:

> ```
> var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>     id: "some-id",
>     icon: {
>         path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
>         strokeColor: "red",
>         scale: 3
>     },
>     map: map,
>     title: "some-title",
>     position: myLatlng
> });
> ```

And here is my improved solution:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            icon:{
                path: 'm 12,2.4000002 c -2.7802903,0 -5.9650002,1.5099999 -5.9650002,5.8299998 0,1.74375 1.1549213,3.264465 2.3551945,4.025812 1.2002732,0.761348 2.4458987,0.763328 2.6273057,2.474813 L 12,24 12.9825,14.68 c 0.179732,-1.704939 1.425357,-1.665423 2.626049,-2.424188 C 16.809241,11.497047 17.965,9.94 17.965,8.23 17.965,3.9100001 14.78029,2.4000002 12,2.4000002 Z',
                fillColor: '#00FF00',
                fillOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 1,
                scale: 2,
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 24),
            },
        });
```

I wanted a specific pin icon so I went and made one with inkscape, then opened the SVG file and copied the svg path into the path into the code, but this works with any SVG path that you put in the "path" attribute of the icon object.

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have 4 ships to set on one single map, so I use the Google Developers example and then twisted it

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

In the function bellow I set 3 more color options:

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
...
var image = {
    url: 'img/bullet_amarelo.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
    size: new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 40)
  };
  var image1 = {
            url: 'img/bullet_azul.png',
            // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
            size: new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
            // The origin for this image is 0,0.
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 40)
          };
  var image2 = {
          url: 'img/bullet_vermelho.png',
          // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
          size: new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
          // The origin for this image is 0,0.
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 40)
        };
  var image3 = {
          url: 'img/bullet_verde.png',
          // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
          size: new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
          // The origin for this image is 0,0.
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 40)
        };
...
}
```

And in the FOR bellow I set one color for each ship:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
...
    if (i==0) var imageV=image;
    if (i==1) var imageV=image1;
    if (i==2) var imageV=image2;
    if (i==3) var imageV=image3;
...
# remember to change icon: image to icon: imageV
}
```

The final result:

http://www.mercosul-line.com.br/site/teste.html

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the [Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) because you can specify the text, text color, fill color and outline color, all using hex color codes, e.g. #FF0000 for red.  You can call it as follows:

```
function getIcon(text, fillColor, textColor, outlineColor) {
  if (!text) text = '•'; //generic map dot
  var iconUrl = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=d&chdp=mapsapi&chl=pin%27i\\%27[" + text + "%27-2%27f\\hv%27a\\]h\\]o\\" + fillColor + "%27fC\\" + textColor + "%27tC\\" + outlineColor + "%27eC\\Lauto%27f\\&ext=.png";
  return iconUrl;
}
```

Then, when you create your marker you just set the icon property as such, where the myColor variables are hex values (minus the hash sign):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  map: map,
  icon: getIcon(null, myColor, myColor2, myColor3)
});
```

You can use `http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=•|FF0000`, which is a bit easier to decipher, as an alternate URL if you only need to set text and fill color.

khurram's answer refers to a 3rd party site that redirects to the Google Charts API.  This means if that person takes down their server you're hosed.  I prefer having the flexibility the Google API offers as well as the reliability of going directly to Google.  Just make sure you specify a value for each of the colors or it won't work.

Comment: unfortunately this API was turned off in March 2019 see developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon the accepted answer, you can create custom `MarkerImages` of any color using the API at `http://chart.googleapis.com`

In addition to changing color, this also changes marker shape, which may be unwanted.

```
const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker(
        position: markerPosition,
        title: markerTitle,
        map: map)
marker.addListener('click', () => marker.setIcon(changeIcon('00ff00'));)

const changeIcon = (newIconColor) => {
    const newIcon = new window.google.maps.MarkerImage(
        `http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?                                      
        chst=d_map_spin&chld=1.0|0|${newIconColor}|60|_|%E2%80%A2`,
        new window.google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new window.google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new window.google.maps.Point(10, 34),
        new window.google.maps.Size(21,34)
    );
    return newIcon
}
```

Source: [free udacity course on google maps apis](https://eu.udacity.com/course/google-maps-apis--ud864)

Answer (score 0):

```
we can do this by adding an icon property and specifying a URL like mention below:
```

icon: {
url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"                           }

```
let map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });

  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    icon: {
      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

var map_marker = $(".map-marker").children("img").attr("src")
        var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(map_marker);

```
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map,
      icon: pinImage
    });
  }
```