# Multi Color Pins on Map

Tags: google-maps

I am using the free version of Google maps and I want to make two different color pins on my map. How can I do this? Is it possible? I tried emailing for help and it seems this is the option they suggest.

Comment: have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064081/javascript-change-google-map-marker-color

Comment: What is the option they suggest?  Are you simply using the user interface or are you using the JavaScript API?  It seems possible with the API but I don't see any option with the user interface.