# How to insert more colors in my map that was generated in R

Tags: r, google-maps, googleway

How do I insert more colors in my function? I managed to insert only 4 (red, blue, green and lavender). But as you can see, cluster 1 and cluster 5 have the same color (blue). However, I didn't want them to be the same. This is a small example, but I have databases with more than 10 clusters, so I would like to adjust my color assignment function.

Executable code below.

Thank you very much!

```
library(googleway)
library(geosphere)

set_key( "API_KEY" )

swf1<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Lat = c(-24.781624,-24.775017,-24.769196,-24.761741,-24.752019,-24.748008), 
                     Lon = c(-49.937369,-49.950576,-49.927608,-49.92762,-49.920608,-49.927707)), 
                    class="data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -6L))

#clusters
d<-as.dist(distm(swf1[,2:1]))
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
clusters<-cutree(fit.average, 5) 
swf1$cluster<-clusters

marker_colors<-c("red", "blue", "green", "lavender")
swf1$color <- marker_colors[swf1$cluster%% 4 +1]
swf1

google_map() %>%
  add_markers(
    data = swf1, lon = "Lon", lat = "Lat", colour="color")
```

[image]

Comment: Those 4 colors are the only colors available if you are using the googleway package, see the `colour` argument here https://rdrr.io/cran/googleway/man/add_markers.html.

Comment: I can't test because apaprently you need an API key.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Is there another package then other than googleway to show the location of properties like I did there? That way, I could try to see if I can put this color differentiation in another package.

Comment: Does it need to use Google Maps?

Comment: Sadly yes! I got it from Openstreetmap already, now it's missing from Google Maps.

Comment: What have you 'got' from OpenStreetMap?

Comment: For same database I tried using OpenStreetMap and it worked. The problem is that for the work I need to do it is necessary to use Google Maps =/

Comment: If you have to use Google Maps as the base maps, but don't care what your markers look like, you can add a `{mapdeck}` scatterplot layer on top of the Google Map - [reference and example here](https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/google_map.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `googleway` package for R has only 'red', 'blue', 'green' or 'lavender' as color options as shown on line 32 here: https://github.com/cran/googleway/blob/master/R/google_map_layer_marker.R#L32

If possible, using additional marker colors will require writing javascript as shown here in the answers from one of the following SO questions:

[Javascript, Change google map marker color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11064081/7547327)

[How can I change the color of a Google Maps marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2472957/7547327)